# Motivation of $p$-spin glass model

Tags: statistics, ising-model, spin-models

In general, the $p$-spin glass model focuses on $p$-body interactions like
$${\displaystyle H({\boldsymbol {\sigma }})=\sum_{i_1,...,i_p} J_{i_{1},\ldots i_{p}} \sigma _{i_{1}}\cdots \sigma _{i_{p}}.}$$
But what is the physical significance of this Hamiltonian? Does there exist any system that has this p-body interaction among p spins? It makes sense to me only when it looks like the Ising model, i.e. p=2 and sum over all adjacent sites...

Comment: looks like a generalization of the  Sherrington–Kirkpatrick model. For $p$ tending to infinity it reproduces the "random energy model": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_energy_model . Also: section 8.2 here: https://web.stanford.edu/~montanar/RESEARCH/BOOK/partB.pdf and this paper: https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.45.79